# Problem with finding XML files in IntelliJ even though they are there

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, path, xml-parsing

First post here so bear with me, also tell me if im doing something wrong :)

I have this problem that in my IDE the application works just fine and it loads all the XML files correctly with all the data.
But when I "Build artifact" to make a release the released application.jar does **NOT** show all of my XML data.

After alot of googling I think it has to do with where I place my XML files and folders because when I tried to recreate the error in my IDE it gave me NullPointerException to the filepath.

This application is to be used by other people so hardcoding the absolute path is not an option.

**Also good to know is that I am have *two* functions.**

**-->** One function for reading only one XML file located in its own package inside src.

**-->** Another function used to read several XML files from a seperate package inside src.

I will paste the code below aswell as a picture showing my package structure in IntelliJ IDE.

**▼ Picture of folder structure here ▼**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9xap.png

I have tried marking **ItemsXML** and **MonsterXML** as resource in project structure but no change.

**▼ Reading of one XML file below ▼**

```
public void ReadItemXMLfile(){
        try{
            String fileName = "src\ItemsXML\items.xml";

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(fileName);

            XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/items/item"); // LOOT ID NUMBER
            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) { 
                Node testNode = nodes.item(i);
                if(testNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element element = (Element) testNode;
                    String idFromItemXml = "";
                    String itemNameFromItemXml = "";
                    idFromItemXml = element.getAttribute("id");
                    itemNameFromItemXml = element.getAttribute("name");
                    for(MonsterXML monster : monstersArrayList){
                        for(MonsterLootXML loot : monster.getLootableItems()){
                            if(loot.getId().equals(idFromItemXml)){
                                loot.setName(itemNameFromItemXml.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + itemNameFromItemXml.substring(1));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException parserConfigurationException) {
            parserConfigurationException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XPathExpressionException xPathExpressionException) {
            xPathExpressionException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException saxException) {
            saxException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**▼Reading of several XML files in a folder below▼**

```
public void ReadMonsterXMLfiles(){
        try{
            File dir = new File("src\\MonsterXML");
            if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                File [] files = dir.listFiles((d, name) -> name.endsWith(".xml"));
                if (files != null) {
                    for (File file: files) {

                        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        factory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
                        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        Document doc = builder.parse(file.getPath());

                        XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                        XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

                        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/monster/@name |  /monster/@experience |  /monster/@manacost | /monster/health/@now");
                        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

                        MonsterXML monsterXML = new MonsterXML();

                        monsterXML.setName(nodes.item(2).getTextContent());
                        monsterXML.setHealth(nodes.item(3).getTextContent());
                        monsterXML.setExperience(nodes.item(0).getTextContent());
                        monsterXML.setManaToSummon(nodes.item(1).getTextContent());
                        monsterXML.setName(monsterXML.getName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + monsterXML.getName().substring(1));

                        // MONSTER LOOT (ID) AND MONSTER LOOT (DROPCHANCE%)
                        expr = xpath.compile("/monster/loot//item"); // LOOT ID NUMBER
                        result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                        nodes = (NodeList) result;
                        MonsterLootXML monsterLootXML = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                            Node testNode = nodes.item(i);
                            if(testNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                                Element element = (Element) testNode;
                                monsterLootXML = new MonsterLootXML();
                                monsterLootXML.setId(element.getAttribute("id"));
                                monsterLootXML.setLootChance(element.getAttribute("chance"));
                                monsterLootXML.setLootChance(Calculations.correctDropChanceNumber(monsterLootXML.getLootChance()));

                                if(element.hasAttribute("countmax")){
                                    monsterLootXML.setAmount(element.getAttribute("countmax"));
                                }
                                else{
                                    monsterLootXML.setAmount("1");
                                }
                                monsterXML.addLootableItems(monsterLootXML);
                            }
                        }
                        monstersArrayList.add(monsterXML);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If anyone knows this well I would love to get some tutoring on discord if possible :)

**Thanks you all!**

Comment: Print out the result of `file.getPath()` from your second example and you might see the difference.

Comment: Another thing to note is that it's quite odd to reference resources through `src\...`, which shouldn't exist in your release.

Comment: @xtratic Hi And thanks for the reply! :) 
Where would be a suitable place to put resources instead of src\... should i make a package(folder) outsice of the src "scope" ?? Thanks

This is what i get when trying the getPath for both the single file and the folder with several file. It all seems to be in order??...

**MonsterFile path: src\MonsterXML\yeti.xml**
**ItemXML path: src\ItemsXML\items.xml**

Comment: The `src` directory is usually not included in your build since you generally don't have source code in your build, but instead have binaries. Just study some typical project organization and build patterns and follow along with those

Comment: That is somewhat what i had in mind, so where would be best to put the xml files?

Comment: Research typical project organization, it will often depend on the build tool you're using. Usually in some `\resources\...` folder somewhere down the line. My key point though is that the `src` directory shouldn't exist in your release

Comment: Gotcha, ill make a new folder outside of the src "scope" then :) lets see.. 
Nope.. didnt work :/ still cant find the files in "released" version

Comment: As mentioned, please study typical project organization. Also, that won't fix your issue, as mentioned please look at the result of `file.getPath()` and that should show you why it's not working in your release

Comment: I am getting 
MonsterFile path: resources\MonsterXML\yeti.xml
ItemXML path: resources\ItemsXML\items.xml

so im not really following on why its not supposed to work in my release...

Comment: I know what's wrong, but I want you to understand so I'll ask you a few questions so that you can work it out: In your release, where exactly is this data that you want and how does it compare to where that data is in your project? Now how exactly are you trying to access it? Answer those questions correctly and you've solved your problem.

Comment: Im guessing what youre saying is that in my release app, I am trying to access a certain file in the **same** folder that the release app is in. So I am trying to reach an XML file inside resources\ItemsXML\items.xml which does not exist. 
Am I on the right track or completely lost? ;D

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to say. How do you think your release app is supposed to access your xml files when you run the app on a different computer?

Comment: My thoughts were that the recourse folder followed along in the released app and could be reached in that way. 
Do you mean that i should just send my XML files along with the application when in release mode?

Comment: Do you know what your release app actually is, and how can you access the resources inside it? hint: `new File("some system path")` is not what you want, as it's trying to find a file on the filesystem. I mean, it *is* possible to get your resources using `File` but it's very ugly and easy to break.

Comment: I thought it was as easy as reading an xml file, but apparently not ^^ 
Are you suggesting getResourceAsStream() function or putting XML outside of the application?

Comment: Correct, `getResourceAsStream` is one of the most straightforward ways to load data from inside your JAR. You can't just try to find the resource on the filesystem because it's zipped into the JAR. However, things will be a bit more difficult than *just* using `getResourceAsStream`, you'll either need to research how to load all resources under a certain path, like you're trying to, or find a new approach entirely.

Comment: Thank you mate! I will look into that or Just throw in the XML files in the folder with the runnable .jar (if that works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this is to **include the XML files in your folder (outside of your .jar)** and then just refeering to that XML file when starting the application.
If you want to have the XML files inside of your .jar and load them from there you need to look up "getResourceAsStream".